# Can I run a script every time the cmd program is run?

Tags: windows, command-line, unicode, utf-8

I want to show unicode character on my windows console. For this I changed the cmd's font to `lucida console` and I'm using `chcp 65001` before every session I will open a program which will display unicode characters. This only works to session where I ran `chcp 65001`. If an external program open the cmd instead of myself I can't control it and call `chcp` before. So I want run it automatically when a new cmd is run (and turn on/off as I want to). Is it possible?

Comment: what you ask for looks very similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109024/how-to-make-unicode-charset-in-cmd-exe-by-default), but I could be wrong!

Comment: It does what I'm looking for but on way I don't want to. As I've mentioned in the post some people did that but you windows system didn't start anymore after reboot.

Comment: oh yes, that link serves only half of your question. For the second part of your question, you could write a windows service to monitor if "cmd" is launched and call your desired program/application as soon as cmd is identified to be a running process. There might be a cleaner approach to it, but this is one of the options.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Autorun](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc756720%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) key in the registry [to run `chcp 65001` for each session]

There are two variables you could use (machine and user hives)
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` and/or
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`

Set `Autorun` (create it if it does not exists, type REG_SZ) to `chcp 65001`